# How to change the left and right bar button items text attributes independently for all View Controllers in AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationitem

In my app, I have many `UIViewControllers` embedded in `UINavigationController` that contains a **cancel** `rightBarButtonItem` and **save** `leftBarButtonItem`.

In every class I have duplicate code to customize the attributes of the bar button items:

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: fontFuturaMedium,
                                                                                             size: fontSize17)! ], 
                                                         for: .normal)

navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: fontFuturaMedium,
                                                                                                 size: fontSize17)! ], 
                                                         for: . highlighted)

navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: fontFuturaBold,
                                                                                             size: fontSize19)! ], 
                                                         for: .normal)

navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: fontFuturaBold,
                                                                                                 size: fontSize19)! ], 
                                                         for: . highlighted)
```

In the **AppDelegate**, I can change the bar button items, which affects both the `leftBarButtonItem` as well as `rightBarButtonItem`:

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: fontFuturaMedium,
                                                                                        size: fontSize17)!],
                                                    for: .normal)
```

However, I would like to change both buttons **independently**, affecting **all** view controllers without having to duplicate code.

I tried to access the `leftBarButtonItem` property of a `UINavigationItem`, but it does not exist. `UINavigationItem` also does not have a `appearance()` property.

I've put the repetitive code in a global function:

```
static public func setNavBar(viewController: UIViewController)
{
    viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes( [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: fontFuturaMedium,
                                                                                                  size: fontSize17)! ],
                                                              for: .normal)
    viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes( [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: fontFuturaMedium,
                                                                                                  size: fontSize17)! ],
                                                              for: .highlighted)
    viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes( [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: fontFuturaBold,
                                                                                                   size: fontSize19)! ],
                                                               for: .normal)
    viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes( [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: fontFuturaBold,
                                                                                                   size: fontSize19)! ],
                                                               for: .highlighted)
}
```

This is obviously much easier and reduces a lot of the duplicate code, because I can just call that one line code in **all** my classes.

However, is there a one liner code that I can put in **AppDelegate** that will replicate throughout **all** the classes, similar to `UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes`, instead of calling `setNavBar` in all the classes?

Thanks.

Comment: Put the code in a method in a `UIViewController` extension.

Comment: Add this in app delegate after closing last brace


extension UIViewController{
    func displayContentController(_ content:UIViewController, controllerName : String)
    { 
           // WRITE YOUR CODE HERE 

    }
}

Comment: Call from view controller -self.displayContentController(self, controllerName: "your wish")

Answer (score 0):

I would sublcass a `UIViewController`, and maybe call it `BaseViewController`; in the `viewDidLoad` of the base view controller I'd put all setup stuff (basically what you do in `setNavBar`).

Then, every view controller of the project will extend the base one.